# Outputting data with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a PHP-function which returns an array and then I move its value to a variable $a. How can I output it to a web page on CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Don't forget to include the variable that you want to be loaded together with the view, like in the following example:

```
class Page extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['my_var'] = $your_var;
        $this->load->view('name_here', $data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Controller:

```
<?php
    class Page extends Controller {

        function index()
        {
            $data['array_var'] = $this->get_some_array(); // this function returned an array
            $this->load->view('name_here', $data);
        }

    }
```

In the View:

```
<?php

foreach ($array_var as $arr):

    echo $arr;

endforeach;

?>
```

I hope this answers  your question.

---

Note: the $data variable won't reflect in the view. CI extracts that variable and returns the array keys as variables like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your output.

Considering you have this array :

```
$a = array(
    'glop', 'test', 'hello', 
);
```

The simplest way to display the items it to join them, using [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) :

```
echo implode(', ', $a) . '<br />';
```

Which will give you :

```
glop, test, hello
```

Another solution would be to loop over the items, using a [`foreach`][2] loop :

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($a as $item) {
    echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($item) . '</li>' . "\n";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

And you'd get this HTML source :

```
<ul><li>glop</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>hello</li>
</ul>
```

i.e. an un-numbered list.

With this, the possibilities are almost un-limited, and you can get pretty much any kind of output you'd want.

If you just want to output the array to see what it contains, for debugging, [`var_dump`][3] and [`print_r`][4] are generally useful :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
echo '</pre>';
```

will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => glop
    [1] => test
    [2] => hello
)
```

And if you install the [Xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/), `var_dump` is even better -- colors and all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by:

```
print_r($a);
```

If you want pretty formatting:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

You could stick stuff between them

```
echo join(",", $a);
```

Or you could give them pretty formatting

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($a as $k => $v)
{
    echo "<li>" . $k . ":" . $v . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I output it to a web page on
>   CodeIgniter?

I suspect you mean to send the variable data to the View. You can do like this:

```
class Page extends Controller {

   function index()
   {
      $data['my_var'] = $your_var;
      $this->load->view('name_here');
   }

}
```

Now you can access the `$data['my_var']` on your View normally.

Comment: You haven't passed the $data variable to the view. (Though it wasn't me who down-voted)

Comment: how i have not passed data var to view? i have said at the last line of my answer: "Now you can access the $data['my_var'] on your View normally".